# Automatically generating Tailwind classes and use them as variables

Tags: tailwind-css

pretty new to Tailwind, looking for a way to generate automatically mat-table column sices. Right now I'm using something like this:

```
$mat-table-col-width: 8;

mat-table {
        mat-header-cell.colTiny,
        mat-footer-cell.colTiny,
        mat-cell.colTiny {
            flex: 0 0 #{$mat-table-col-tiny-width}rem;
        }
}
```

Now I'd rather generate different sizes, e.g. `col-w-1, col-w-2, col-w-3` etc. pp.. How to do this using the tailwind.config.js? Using a custom template where I never needed to modify anything.

And can the sizes be exported as variables, too? Since I need to calculate the actual min width:

```
min-width: #{($mat-table-col-tiny-width * 3) + ($mat-table-col-width * 5)}rem;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using min-width https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-width#min-width-scale and/or flex https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex#flex-values ? Don't know what you're trying to accomplish… should it be a CSS grid?

Comment: No, I'm looking for a way to generate a range of own custom classes **and** expose their values as scss variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> expose their values as scss

If you're working with a team that mixes Tailwind and Sass, ask around for a preferred approach. Otherwise, consider making the paradigm shift to doing all of this in Tailwind / JS. Details below.

> generate automatically [`flex` and `min-width`] sices

(A) Simplest is to define `flex` classes and `min-width` classes in the Tailwind config:

```js
flex: {
  tiny: '0 0 1rem',
  sm: '0 0 2rem',
  md: '0 0 3rem',
  lg: '0 0 4rem',
},
minWidth: {
  tiny: '1rem',
  sm: '2rem',
  md: '3rem',
  lg: '4rem',
},
```

Fiddle: https://play.tailwindcss.com/K9lWFOj3xU?file=config

That gives you

```css
.flex-tiny {
  flex: 0 0 1rem
}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 0 0 2rem
}

.flex-2 {
  flex: 0 0 3rem
}

.flex-3 {
  flex: 0 0 4rem
}

.min-w-tiny {
  min-width: 1rem
}

.min-w-1 {
  min-width: 2rem
}

.min-w-2 {
  min-width: 3rem
}

.min-w-3 {
  min-width: 4rem
}
```

(B) You could refactor that to reuse values, starting point something like

```js
const sizes = {
  tiny: '1rem',
  sm: '2rem',
  md: '3rem',
  lg: '4rem',
}

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      flex: /* …manipulate `sizes` to give the desired object… */,
      minWidth: sizes,
    },
  },
}
```

with the same CSS result.

> generate a range of own custom classes

(C) If you *must* have class names that aren't part of Tailwind (`col-w-…` not `flex-…` for flex classes) you'll have to write a plugin. If your plugin references the config (docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#referencing-the-user-s-config) you could end up with a setup like

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      mySizes: {
        tiny: 1,
        sm: 2,
        md: 3,
        lg: 4,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    // a plugin that generates
    // `.col-w-<name> { flex: 0 0 <val>rem }`
    // and `.minwidth-<name> { min-width: <val>rem }`
    // rules from the `mySizes` config
  ],
}
```

> pretty new to Tailwind

I recommend try committing to A or B to start and updating your markup as necessary, to get a feeling for the Tailwind idiom of using the classes generated by the core plugins.